# Adding range sliders on Google's Data Layer Map to filter data

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, geojson

Is it possible to create input functions like a slider, radio or checkbox to allow users to filter geojson data loaded into Google's Data Layer while using `map.data.loadgeojson()`?

My understanding is that the load or `addGeoJson` functions on the data layer creates one single layer. How does one build an input feature that changes the way data is displayed on a map?

Thanks in advance and please let me know if the question is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to load multiple Data Layers on one map.

The part that may be unclear from the docs is that you get one data layer included by default when you create a map, as `map.data`. e.g.

```
var myMap = new google.maps.Map(..);
myMap.data.loadGeoJson(...);
```

You can however create as many data layers as you wish.

```
function styleFeature(feature) {
   // style the feature here
}

var layer1 = new google.maps.Data();
layer1.setMap(myMap);
layer1.setStyle(styleFeature);
```

The important part is that you need to set the map and that you set any customisations on the new layer objects (e.g. `layer1`), not on `map.data`.

In the example I gave, you could also do it all in one line.

```
var layer1 = new google.maps.Data({ map: myMap, style: styleFeature });
```